# Flickr and Flickraw gem authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flickr

I'm trying to use the Flickraw gem to upload some images to my account in Flickr. I get this to work, but how to get the access code, without to visit Flickr page, like this:

```
token = flickr.get_request_token
auth_url = flickr.get_authorize_url(token['oauth_token'], :perms => 'delete')
puts "Open this url in your process to complete the authication process : #{auth_url}"
puts "Copy here the number given when you complete the process."
verify = gets.strip
...
```

I don´t understand this process.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the auth process is done using OAuth, explained here: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html

It's basically making the request to the flickr server getting an access token for the currently signed in user and returning that to an call back URL on your server(The docs explain it way better and in much more details so I recommend reading that instead).

If however you want to use the application only in your name you can look into other authentication mechanisms, explained here: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.spec.html

The one you want to use - as it looks to me - is the non web based authentication. This is a much easier way to authenticate and only uses a key and secret for authentication. Which also seems to be supported by the FlickRaw gem: http://hanklords.github.io/flickraw/ (Look at the first simple example)

Comment: The first example does not upload images. When uploading, we need the token. The Flickraw docs says: # You need to be authentified to do that, see the previous examples.

Comment: I think that Flickr is not the way to go. I need a place that my application can upload images, seamless to the user.

Comment: If you want other users to upload content to a central place I don't Flickr would be the best place to go, if I'm not mistaken I think it's also not allowed to use Flickr for this purpose. A better solution would be something like S3 and use carrierwave: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave